# sum of square root is constant for all isogonal conjugates wrt a quadrilateral

Tags: contest-math, euclidean-geometry, quadrilateral

I am interested in [a question](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1486514p8704138) by @guangzhou-2015 with no solutions. Equivalent form:

> An ellipse with foci $E,F$ is tangent to four sides of quadrilateral $ABCD$, then
> $$\sqrt{EA \times EC \times FA \times FC}+\sqrt{EB \times ED \times FB \times FD}=\sqrt{AB \times BC \times CD \times DA}$$
> [image]

By dimensional analysis, the quantity in this equation is square root of 4th power of length, so I guess it is a relation of area.

This equation is equivalent to

> $$\sqrt{EA \times EC \times FA \times FC}+\sqrt{EB \times ED \times FB \times FD}=\text{constant}$$for all isogonal conjugate pairs $(E,F)$ wrt convex quadrilateral $ABCD$ and inside it.

We get the right hand side if we evaluate this expression at $(A,C)$ or $(B,D)$.

The points $P,Q$ should be restricted to inside the quadrilateral, otherwise the square roots need to change sign. In the "foci" form of this question, we implicitly assumed $P,Q$ are inside $ABCD$ by using an "ellipse" rather than an arbitrary conic.

Answer (score 0):

Using [$\rm(eq1)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4796543) by symmetry
$$
\frac{AE}{AB}=\frac{CF⋅DE}{BF⋅CD}
$$
and
$$
\frac{AF}{AD}=\frac{FB⋅CE}{BC⋅ED}
$$
we get
\begin{align}
\sqrt{AE⋅AF⋅CE⋅CF\over AB⋅AD⋅CB⋅CD}&=
\sqrt{\frac{CF⋅DE}{BF⋅CD}⋅\frac{FB⋅CE}{BC⋅ED}⋅\frac{CE⋅CF}{CB⋅CD}}\\
&=\frac{CE⋅CF}{CB⋅CD}
\end{align}
Similarly
$$
\sqrt{BE⋅BF⋅DE⋅DF\over AB⋅AD⋅CB⋅CD}=\frac{DE⋅DF}{DA⋅DC}
$$
Substituting into [$\rm(eq2)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4796543) we get
$$
\sqrt{AE⋅AF⋅CE⋅CF\over AB⋅AD⋅CB⋅CD}+\sqrt{BE⋅BF⋅DE⋅DF\over AB⋅AD⋅CB⋅CD}=1
$$
Therefore
$$
\sqrt{AE⋅AF⋅CE⋅CF}+\sqrt{BE⋅BF⋅DE⋅DF}=\sqrt{AB⋅AD⋅CB⋅CD}
$$