# ellipse inscribed in a quadrilateral

Tags: euclidean-geometry, quadrilateral

An ellipse with foci $E,F$ is tangent to four sides of quadrilateral $ABCD$, then
$$\tag{eq1} AB⋅EC⋅DF=FA⋅BE⋅CD$$
The order of points in the equation is interesting: $ABECDF$ is a cyclic shift of $FABECD$.
$$\tag{eq2}\frac{CE⋅CF}{CB⋅CD}+\frac{DE⋅DF}{DA⋅DC}=1$$
[image]

These identities are needed in my proof of [another identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4796520/745350).

Comment: Does Marden theorem help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The identity holds for the complex number $a,b,c,d,e,f$ corresponding to points $A,B,C,D,E,F$:
$$
\frac{(a-b) (e-c) (d-f)}{(f-a) (b-e) (c-d)}=-1
$$

Taking $\arg$, we get $\arg\frac{a-b}{a-f}+\arg\frac{e-c}{e-b}+\arg\frac{d-f}{d-c}\equiv0\pmod{2\pi}$.

Taking $|\cdot|$, we get the desired identity $\rm(eq1)$.

---

By Corollary 2.1 in [a blogpost](https://www.llddeddym.site/posts/2020/10/2020-10-06-QL-Cu1/), isogonal conjugation is just $P\mapsto\frac1P$, in a suitable coordinate system!

> **推论2.1**：给定完全四边形及其一对等角共轭点$P,Q$，$\triangle MA _ {13}P\stackrel{+}{\sim}\triangle MA _ {24}Q$.
>
> *Proof*. 将$P,Q$视为$\triangle _ 1$的等角共轭点，由**定理2.1**立得.$\quad\Box$
>
> 这说明存在一个以$M$为中心的反演反射变换将$P$和$gP$互变，这就给出了$g$的一个显式表示，也就是说存在以$M$为中心的一个复坐标系使得$gP=\dfrac{1}{P}$.

In our setting, Corollary 2.1 implies the complex identity
$$\tag1\label1
(m-a)(m-c)=(m-e)(m-f)
$$
Miquel point of $a,b,c,d$ is defined by
$$\tag2\label2
(m-a)(m-c)=(m-b)(m-d)$$
By scaling the coordinates, set $(m-a)(m-c)=(m-b)(m-d)=1$.
By translating the coordinates, set $m=0$, then \eqref{1} and \eqref{2} becomes
$$ac=bd=ef=1$$
Plugging in our identity
$$\frac{(a-b) (e-c) (d-f)}{(f-a) (b-e) (c-d)}+1=\frac{(a-b) (e-a^{-1}) (b^{-1}-e^{-1})}{(e^{-1}-a) (b-e) (a^{-1}-b^{-1})}+1=0$$
we are done!

---

This choice of coordinates greatly simplifies our computation.
We can use the same method to prove identity $\rm(eq2)$:
$$\tag3\label3
\frac{(c-e) (c-f)}{(c-b) (c-d)}+\frac{(d-e) (d-f)}{(d-a) (d-c)}=1$$
Plugging in $f=e^{-1},b=d^{-1},a=c^{-1}$
$$
LHS=\frac{{(c - e)(c - e^{-1})}}{{(c - d^{-1})(c - d)}} + \frac{{(d - e)(d - e^{-1})}}{{(d - c^{-1})(d - c)}}
$$
After simplification, this is equal to $1$, we are done!

---

By symmetry, we can replace $c$ with $a$ in \eqref{3} to get another identity:
$$\frac{(a-e)(a-f)}{(a-b)(a-d)}+\frac{(d-e) (d-f)}{(d-a) (d-c)}=1$$
In fact, the first term is invariant when replacing $c$ with $a$:
$$\frac{(c-e) (c-f)}{(c-b) (c-d)}=\frac{(a-e)(a-f)}{(a-b)(a-d)}$$